# Выборка в mysqli в PHP по дате и времени

Tags: php, база-данных, mysqli

вот такой запрос срабатывает, находит нужную строку

```
$x = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE time = '2020-02-03 10:00:00'"));
```

а если дата берется из переменной то не работает:

```
$param = '2020-02-03 10:00:00';
$x = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE time = $param"));
```

нужно именно из переменной, в чем может быть дело?

Comment: Что значит не работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В самом запросе нужно ставить ковычки, ибо Mysql без разницы какого типа там переменная, тип нужно указывать в запросе.

```
$param = '2020-02-03 10:00:00';
$x = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE time = '{$param}'"));
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло